# Installing cc.net on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, cruisecontrol.net

Trying to configure cc.net on windows vista but keep getting errors. Now getting the following error

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found 
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension 
configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file 
should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Can anyone plz tell which MIME type to add to get it work

Answer (score 2):

First go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 via the command line and run aspnet_regiis.exe /i.
Next check the ISAPI and CGI Registrations under IIS for the site and make sure the ASP.NET 2.0.x is there and is enabled.  I've seen ASP.NET 2.0.x be listed even though it wasn't installed properly and I've also seen the ASP.NET 2.0.x web server extension be disabled, both cause a similar issue to what you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten this yet (I see it's an old post) first do the  aspnet_regiis.exe /i as recommended by wegrata, then

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD.EXE migrate config "Default Web Site/ccnet"
```

Also, instead of doing the aspnet_regiis bit, you *should* be able to accomplish the same by turning on ASP.NET from Add/Remove windows components. This was what I had to do on Win 7